# MongoDB: Get count of Array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Given these documents:

```
db.orders.insert( {OrderId:1, OrderItems: [{OrderItemId:1, Qty:1}, {OrderItemId:2, Qty:1} ]} );
db.orders.insert( {OrderId:2, OrderItems: [{OrderItemId:1, Qty:1}, {OrderItemId:2, Qty:2} ]} );
```

I'd like to get the count of all OrderItems where the Qty = 1 (expected result 3).  This is how I think to write the query, but it returns 2 (1 for each Order document):

```
db.orders.find({"OrderItems.Qty":1}).count();
```

How can I query to find the count of all OrderItems where the Qty = 1?

Answer (score 4):

Just to be clear for others reading this thread.

The OP's command `db.orders.find({"OrderItems.Qty":1}).count();` basically counts the number of Documents where any order item has a quantity of 1.

However, the OP wants a count of all OrderItems where the quantity is one. The problem here is that we're not counting Documents. We're counting items within an array within a Document. Hence the need for javascript and some form of special reduce operation.

Comment: Is this more of a comment or answer? I don't understand it as an answer but that could be because I am unfamiliar with the code, but I believe this answer got flagged for a reason

Comment: No, this is clearly not an answer, rather commentary on the question and other answers. There are no "threads" on SO either, just questions and answers. This should be a comment on the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use JavaScript:

```
db.orders.group(
{
  key: null, 
  cond: {'OrderItems.Qty':1}, 
  initial: {count: 0}, 
  reduce: function(el, running)
  {                                                                                                       
    running.count += el.OrderItems.filter(function(el)                                                    
    {                                                                                                     
      return el.Qty == 1;                                                                                 
    }).length;                                                                                            
  }                                                                                                       
});
```

Comment: Can you help me out with the syntax to use inside the Mongo shell?  (mongo.exe)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {$unwind: '@OrderItems'},
  {$match : {'OrderItems.Qty':1}},
  {$group : { _id : null, 'countOfQty1':{$sum:'$OrderItems.Qty'} }}
]);
```

Comment: it's community wiki now. If you think it is not right, you may change it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you in the shell without JavaScript (so it'll be a lot quicker);

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {$unwind:'$OrderItems'},
  {$match: {'OrderItems.Qty':1}},
  {$group : { 
      _id : "Qty1",
      sum: {$sum:1}
  }}
]);
```

Although it's unfortunate your data is structured like that if this is a common query. Having to do an `$unwind` is relatively expensive. It's a shame your order items aren't laid out as separate documents tagged with the order ID instead of orderID documents containing arrays of order items...in other words, the reverse of what you have. That would be much easier and more efficient to process.